# Plotting temperature data with sensor positions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a room in which temperature sensors are scattered randomly. The information is:

```
vector x # x position of all sensors
vector y # y position of all sensors
vector T # temperature values of all sensors
```

I want to display the info graphically, colored if possible. I tried the mesh it said `z must be a matrix`.

[This thread](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243056) is very close but I was not able to understand the code. I also did a search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909978/how-can-i-visualize-plot-temperature-gradient-using-matlab) but could not understand it either.

Comment: For the interpolation check out http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html that may be what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to use `scatter` to plot color-coded temperature information at irregular x,y positions:

```
%# take some sample data
x = [1.6294 1.8116 0.2540 1.8268 1.2647 0.1951 0.5570 1.0938 1.9150 1.9298 0.3152 1.9412 1.9143 0.9708 1.6006 0.2838 0.8435 1.8315 1.5844 1.9190]
y= [1.3115 0.0714 1.6983 1.8680 1.3575 1.5155 1.4863 0.7845 1.3110 0.3424 1.4121 0.0637 0.5538 0.0923 0.1943 1.6469 1.3897 0.6342 1.9004 0.0689]
T =[0.2072 0.4849 Inf 0.1919 -0.0632 0.0857 -0.2072 0.3756 0.1881 0.1575 -0.1752 0.0640 -0.1117 -0.0623 -0.1140 -0.2051 -0.1817 -0.0420 -0.3398 0.1215]

%# plot using scatter
dfig,scatter(x,y,[],T,'filled')

%# use more sensible colormap, have it range from -0.5 to 0.5 normalized temperature
colormap('hot')
caxis([-0.5 0.5])

%# change background for better contrast
set(gca,'color',[0.5 0.5 0.5])
set(gcf,'color',[0.5 0.5 0.5])

%# highlight outliers (e.g. overly hot readings) with a circle
hold on
hotIdx = T>0.5;
plot(x(hotIdx),y(hotIdx),'og','markerSize',14)
```

[image]

Here's a different colormap, plus text with data values:

```
cmap = colormap('hot');
cmap = [flipud(cmap);cmap];
colormap(cmap)
caxis([-0.5 0.5])
hold on,for i=1:length(x),text(x(i),y(i)+0.03,num2str(T(i)),'horizontalalignment','center');end
```

[image]

Comment: @pac: So what did you have in mind? Did you want to plot your temperature data on a regular grid instead of plotting it at the original locations?

Comment: maybe more interesting or real. by the way how can i make this divided into 3 ranges normal temp (normalized) -0.5-->0.5 heat -0.7-->0.5 or 0.5-->0.7 else abnormal

Comment: @pac: Yes, that should be no problem. I'll add that later. To see how your data looks "real", have you tried my solution with your real data? There should be much more interesting patterns. If you mean another sort of "interesting", i.e. more "flashy" visualization, it would help if you posted some of your data so that we can see what to do with it.

Comment: here are some results: x = 1.6294 1.8116 0.2540 1.8268 1.2647 0.1951 0.5570 1.0938 1.9150 1.9298 0.3152 1.9412 1.9143 0.9708 1.6006 0.2838 0.8435 1.8315 1.5844 1.9190  y=1.3115    0.0714    1.6983    1.8680    1.3575    1.5155    1.4863    0.7845    1.3110    0.3424    1.4121    0.0637    0.5538    0.0923    0.1943    1.6469    1.3897    0.6342    1.9004    0.0689
T =0.2072    0.4849       Inf    0.1919   -0.0632    0.0857   -0.2072    0.3756    0.1881    0.1575   -0.1752    0.0640   -0.1117   -0.0623   -0.1140   -0.2051   -0.1817  -0.0420   -0.3398    0.1215

Comment: @pac: I've plotted the scatter plot for your data. I do think you can see some regional trends, but the data is a bit sparse IMHO for interpolation. I've chosen to circle the "bad" spots, but you could modify the `plot` line to plot filled circles (or stars or whatever) over the bad data in any color you like.

Comment: can i use T to be an array of characters?             also i still need to have a symetry wrt the zero. ie red-wht red

Comment: @pac: If `T` is an array of characters, you can use `text` to write the contents of `T` all over the map. If you want a symmetric colormap, use: `cmap = colormap('hot');cmap = [flipud(cmap);cmap];`

Comment: :I have added your lines 'cmap = colormap('hot');cmap = [flipud(cmap);cmap];' The code did not work unless I removed the 'command scatter(x,y,[],T,'filled').' now there exist no colors just the circle. What is missing in my code!

Comment: ok sorry for the mistake I typed T instead should be t but the cmap where it is used nothing changed what is missing

Comment: @pac: once you constructed `cmap`, you apply the colormap as `colormap(cmap)`

Comment: yes I did. the values -0.5 0.5 is there but all white  @Jonas

Comment: Hi @Jonas I have tried it but instead of getting like yours I am getting 4 sections orange yellow wht(from 0.5-0.3)then orng yellow white (from 0.2-0)...but if upload the fig here the figure is like yours WEIRD

Comment: THERE are black spot while the grid shows only wht orange yellow

Comment: one more question @Jonas How to increase the black part around zero?

Comment: Use the [colormapeditor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormapeditor.html) to modify the current figure's colormap, or add a few rows of black in the middle.

Comment: thanks @Jonas ur great. Cool instead of hot was also interesting.But i want also to ask if i want to make symmetry for hot spots. hotIdx = (t>o.5 | t<-0.5) will work right?

Comment: @pac: yes, as long as you use the number 0 instead of the letter o :)

Answer (score 0):

You must cross reference your x,y and T vectors in a matrix and use two axis vectors as first and second argument. (For surf, which I use).

Basically something like

```
for i = 1:n
    matrix(x(i),y(i)) = T(i)
end
```

And make two vectors for the axis.

(I'm not sure if it's () or [] for accesing matrix)

If you don't know what I mean I can take some more time to provide you with a full example.

(Also look "help surf" for the coloring)

```
matrix = zeros(4000,4000);

axisX = 0:1:3999;
axisY = 0:1:3999;

for i = 1:n
    x(i) = round(1000*x(i));
    y(i) = round(1000*y(i));
end

for i = 1:n
    matrix(x(i),y(i)) = T(i);
end

surf(axisX,axisY,matrix);
```

Comment: My temperature values are :Columns 1 through 17 Inf 0.0092 -0.0128 0.1223 0.0219 0.3628 0.0624 0.3609 -0.1446 0.1053 -0.0521 0.1200 0.1188 -0.4372 -0.2654 -0.2882 0.0804 Columns 18 through 20 0.2940 -0.0654 0.1625 so the following error was given by matlab/////////; ??? Attempted to access (1.62945,1.31148); index must be a positive integer or logical. when i used your code

Comment: Ah I found that the problem is with the xy coordinates which are not integers my values of x for example are :x =

  Columns 1 through 17

    2.2133    3.9238    2.0093    3.5498    3.6346    3.7374    2.1689    2.7996    2.5197    3.6001    2.8628    3.8213    2.3637    2.5276    2.2911    2.2721    3.7386

  Columns 18 through 20

    3.1594    3.0997    2.2899
any advice?

Comment: Discretise to a certain point. Like you value seems to range from 2 ->  4 : make the matrix like 4000*4000 so you can express 3.6346 as the index 3634. All you will have to do after is change the scale in the graphs. If you want more or less precision you can use bigger or smaller matrix. To discretise you could simply do "round(value*1000)", that's the classical way.

Comment: I edited my answer for a clear example, but to be honest I don't think that will do what you really want. You should look up bilinear interpolation and check out if there is a built in matlab function that does that.

Comment: This is overly complicated, and also contains errors. You don't need to have integer values in your axes matrices. And you're only setting values along the diagonal of the matrix.

Comment: I'm not only setting values along the diagonal of the matrix.

Comment: `matrix(x(i),y(i)) = T(i);` - values are set at (1,1), (2,2) etc. Since `i` is the index in both dimensions, you *can't* get off the diagonal. (2,1) can't happen, for example.

Comment: x = [ 2 4 5 3], y = [4 5 6 3], matrix(x(1),y(1)) = matrix(2,4).

Comment: @sword22 Apologies, I was thinking axisX rather than just x.  You are correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have temperature readings on a regular grid, i.e. each combination of x and y values has a temperature reading, then you can use `surf` to plot your data with a pretty surface connecting them. You'll need to form a new temperature matrix `T2` of size `[m,n]` where `n=size(x)`, `m=size(y)`, such that `Z(i,j)` contains the temperature at `(x(j), y(i))`. Then you can call `surf(x, y, T2)`.

In the general case, you can just do `plot3(x, y, T)` to get a set of points.

Comment: Well you are right @tmpearce it is complicated. there should be a better way.Thanks anyways Sword22 for your help. By the way the area is divided into grids so x and y coordinate range will change. But the total number of nodes are the same in each grid